# how to add watcher in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying add watcher in my demo.I am able to add watch in object like that

```
$scope.$watch('username',function(newvalue,oldvalue){
        console.log(newvalue +":"+oldvalue);
        $scope.newmessage=newvalue.toUpperCase();
    })
```

It is working fine .But when I am trying to test it gives me error here is my code

```
describe('value check', function() {
  var $scope,
    ctrl,
    fac,
    $httpBackend;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');

  });
  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('cntrl', {
        '$scope': $scope
      });
    };

  }));

  describe('watch check', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      $scope.$digest();
    });

    it('should init', function(){
      expect($scope.newmessage).toBeUndefined();
    });

    it('should upper case',function() {
      var controller = createController();
      $scope.message='naveen';
      $scope.$digest();
      expect($scope.newmessage).toEqual('NAVEEN');
    });
  });


  it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
    var response = [{
      "name": "naveen"
    }, {
      "name": "parveen"
    }]
    $httpBackend.whenGET('data.json').respond(response);
    var controller = createController();

    $httpBackend.expectGET('data.json').respond(response);

    $scope.getData();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect($scope.data[0].name).toEqual('naveen')
  });
});
```

Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/NhazRDVM01DCDQWw8yzV?p=preview

Comment: `username` is not defined anywhere, missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error was unexpected request and that can be solved by mocking data.json request in `should uppercase` test case.

Second error can be fixed by doing `$scope.username = 'naveen'` instead of `$scope.message = 'naveen'` because you are actually watching for username change, not message change.

Third error is that when you initialise watch, it was getting triggered with undefined new value. To fix this, check if it's undefined or not in the controller:

```
if (newvalue) {
       $scope.newmessage = newvalue.toUpperCase();
}
```

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OBUcoNGPdfRwy3hwR4KZ?p=preview

Comment: @chantu why it is not working http://plnkr.co/edit/ze9DoPpmGC5TKOVGajaE?p=preview

Comment: I just remove create controller  function

Comment: do you have any idea ?